# hvFloat: wrong page number via addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I'm still typesetting a book where I have about 10 pictures in every huge part and I want to add their captions to the ToC, not on a separate list of figures. Fot that, I'm using `\addcontentsline` to add some of the caption text as section entry of ToC.
Some pictures will have to be put horizontally, so I have to rotate them together with the caption. While I tried to adjust options of **hvFloat** (v1.1, 2012/03/04) package to my needs, I discovered that the command `\addcontentsline` produces wrong page numbers, no matter where it is placed - before `\hvFloat` or after. Neither did adding of `\clearpage` help. But if LoF is produced, the page numbers there are correct.
I'm currently using the `sidewaysfigure` environment, because until now, all of horizontal figures take the whole page, so I can do that. But the question of why this command does not work properly with `\hvFloat` is still open. Does the package cause it?
Besides, when I've tried to place a vertical figure with `\hvFloat` which also should fill the page, an additional empty page before the float was produced. If I specify `floatPos=h` (or anything else, for that matter), it will move on a page after ToC.
And the images themselves do not fit perfectly inside the layout frame, because they are shifted - does the package create an additional white space before or around the float? And if I choose the `nonFloat`-option, it shifts outside the layout frame by some centimeters.
Here comes the MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,russian,open=any]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=14.8cm, paperheight=21.0cm, top=1.1cm, bottom=1.8cm, twoside, inner=0.9cm, outer=1.8cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=1cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0cm, hoffset=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{floatpag} 
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.95}

\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0mm}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\floatpagestyle{empty}

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.tiff,.tif,.png,.jpg}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
\kern -1pt
\hrule width 4.5cm height 0.5pt
\kern 4pt
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[EC,OC]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{2} 
\cftsetindents{section}{5mm}{4mm} 
\setlength{\cftparskip}{0.2\baselineskip} 
\cftsetpnumwidth{10mm}
\cftsetrmarg{1.5cm} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\clearpage

\newgeometry{top=0.75cm, bottom=0.75cm, twoside, inner=0.7cm, outer=1cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=0cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0cm, hoffset=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, marginparwidth=0cm}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\captionsetup{width=14cm}
\includegraphics[width=1\textheight]{Newsize90.pdf}
\caption[]{\emph{...Picture via "sidewaysfigure", captionskip=0 on both sides, size is ok...\\if second line appears, picture with capture will shift to the left, outside the frame}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\emph{...Picture inserted and rotated via sidewaysfigure environment, size is ok. Page number in ToC is CORRECT...}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\clearpage

\restoregeometry

\lipsum 

\clearpage

\newgeometry{top=0.75cm, bottom=0.75cm, twoside, inner=0.7cm, outer=1cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=0cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0cm, hoffset=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, marginparwidth=0cm}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\emph{...Picture rotated via hvFloat, size is ok, but shifted down by 1mm, page number in ToC is WRONG...}}
\hvFloat[floatPos=p, capWidth=1.1, capPos=b, rotAngle=90, objectPos=l]{figure}{
\includegraphics[width=1\textheight]{Newsize90.pdf}}[rotated - LoF page number is CORRECT]{\emph{...Picture rotated via hvFloat, size is ok, but shifted down by 1mm \\if second line appears, only caption moves to the right, outside the frame...}}{}

\clearpage

\restoregeometry

\lipsum 

\clearpage

\newgeometry{top=0.75cm, bottom=0.75cm, twoside, inner=0.7cm, outer=1cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=0cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0cm, hoffset=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, marginparwidth=0cm}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\emph{...Picture not rotated, placed via hvFloat, size fits, empty page before float is produced, ToC page number is WRONG...}}

\captionsetup{aboveskip=1mm, width=11.8cm}
\hvFloat{figure}{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Newsize.pdf}}[not rotated - LoF page number is CORRECT]{\emph{...Picture not rotated, placed via hvFloat, size fits, but fig+cap seem to be placed at the center of page; empty page before float is produced...}}{}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

All files created by my TeXstudio 2.6.0 together with both pictures I used are in  [this zip-file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33041425/MWE.7z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
\hvFloat{figure}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{blah blah}%%%%%%%%
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Newsize.pdf}}[not rotated - LoF page number is CORRECT]{\emph{...Picture not rotated, placed via hvFloat, size fits, but fig+cap seem to be placed at the center of page; empty page before float is produced...}}{}
```

Answer (score 2):

> “We all float down here!” ― Stephen King, It [Eso]

Even *It* said that, is not true. In LaTeX just a float fly from one page to other. If you want that `\addcontentsline` will not remain in the ground, tuck it in the float.

I tried to move the `\addcontentsline` stuff inside the captions of our example and seem to work.